# LWC Testing framework

Tags: unit-test, lightning-web-components, lwc-jest

We have a really nasty problem with the LWC Jest tests. Every single test takes too much time to execute on Windows. For example, the very same tests take 5 secs to execute on Mac and over 1 minute on Windows. I suspect the problem might be this: https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/7631

Here's [a repo](https://github.com/salesforce/sfdx-lwc-jest) with the tests we launched for checking.

So the question is: is it possible to utilize any other test framework (e.g. Mocha) with LWC? Any experience share is much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would discourage you from trying another JS testing framework for this issue. Although it's feasible, it would require some work because we (Salesforce) provide essential testing features in the Jest plugin that you would have to reimplement yourself on another testing framework. These include the wire testing service and the Lightning base component mocks.

Looking at the Jest bug you linked, it seems like a consistent issue and it might get some attention so I suggest monitoring it.

One workaround worth trying is running tests with [WSL](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10) as this user reported:

> I cumulate the slowness of jest 24 and windows 10 (800s for 400 tests!). The faster way I found to speed up all of this is to use wsl instead of powershell or cmd. Now my tests takes "only" 189s.

Comment: yeah, I completely understand that there are some additional things implemented in LWC Jest. Unfortunately, I cannot run it through WSL, as I have Win7. Anyway, thanks for your answer!